# HDD I/O error on high usage

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, laptop, ssd

I've got an Asus X550V notebook that has a 1TB HGST HTS7210 HDD.
I've managed to replace the optical drive with the hard drive, and insert an SSD into the original HDD bay.

So far so good it's working almost perfectly, but the HDD behaviors quite strangely. Under normal circumstances it's working, but if the disk usage reaches 100% (according to windows task manager) - 9 times out of 10 - the drive becames unresponsive until a complete system restart. It's happening for example, when I'm copying a file from the SSD to the HDD or just downloading a file directly to the HDD.

I've checked the drive using several tools like CrystalDiskInfo, SpeedFan and SeaTools but it passed all the tests and received a 100% for the S.M.A.R.T. check.

At this point I have no idea either what is causing the problem or how to solve it, so any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried putting it back as it originally was to see if the symptom recurs?

Comment: No, I haven't. It's a quite difficult task to do because in order to put the computer back to it's original state I'd need to remove the whole keyboard (including the touchpad) and unfortunately it's made of weak plastic so it would break very easily. As the last option I will try this method, but just for now let's assume that neither the drive nor the connection is wrong.